# Deterministic finite automaton (DFA) accept strings

Tags: dfa

Construct a DFA that accept the following string A(B|(BC+))*C , i do not understand the sequence of the string really well

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The string `A(B|(BC+))*C` is usually a regular expression. In your case:

```
| means OR
+ means one or more occurrence of previous symbol
* means zero or more occurrence of previous symbol
```

The basic conversion:

```
AB  --> {q0, A, q1}, {q1, B, q2}
A|B --> {q0, A, q1}, {q0, B, q1}
A+  --> {q0, A, q1}, {q1, A, q1}
A*  --> {q0, A, q0}
```

`{q0, s, q1}` means transition from state `q0` to `q1` by reading symbol `s`

You can try it first by yourself for the case you have. If you find difficulties, give comment.